# how to merge two disk Ubuntu primary partitions

Tags: partitioning

I installed by mistake two primary Ubuntu partitions on dual booting PC (64-bit) with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04.
First I tried Someting Else when installing Ubuntu 12.04, then I changed my mind and installed Ubuntu 12.04
without defining partition. I have about 1TB available for Windows 7, PC starts from Ubuntu as default.
Result was two primary partitions in Ubuntu, 890 GB and 16 GB. Ubuntu OS resides in partition 16 GB.
Then I installed software OpenFoam and it was installed in partition 890 GB. I cannot use it as it stands.

What would you advice? Reinstall Ubuntu? Use GParted ? I already have a boot CD for GParted.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, having two partitions -- one small for the OS and a large one for /home and the data -- is a very good idea. Instead of merging the partitions, I would rather move my /home from the smaller partition to the large one, and mount the large one as the new /home.

There are at least two very good reasons for that. (i) reinstalling the system does not increase heart rate, as chances of incidentally wiping out your data by allowing the installer to format the partition are smaller (ii) smaller partitions tend to have better access times.

If you really, really want to merge, however, then you do this:

1. move all data from one partition to another
2. delete the partition from which you have moved the data
3. expand the remaining partition with gparted

It doesn't matter which partition is first, as long as they are next to each other.